# Not able to play video using Google Home through my app

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, api-ai

I am trying to create an app on Google Home using API AI, my app involves playing of audio and video. I am able to play audio now but I don't know how to play video on ChromeCast-enabled TV using Google Home.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping stackoverflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Direct control of other Chromecast devices is not yet supported by Home. Although there was some announcement of this at I/O, there was no indication when or how this would be done.

In the interim, you might be able to use a control application that runs on a phone or laptop and have a separate communication channel between your Home and this control app. That would be far from an ideal environment, however.